# Offsetting text in a UILabel vertically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

[Layout without header background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evql3.png)

[Layout with header background so you can see its centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOfv2.png)

Im trying to make the header appear centered in the design, but because of the top space in the cells, it looks as it has been placed to high. How can I make it appeared on all screen sizes? Im worried if i use a offset in points that it it will be too small of an offset on big screens and to big of an offset on small screens?

Currently i do it it like this:

```
func adjustLayoutToFrame(){
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        let cellHeight = screenHeight / 9
        let headerHeight = cellHeight*2

        weekHeaderLabel.frame.size.height = headerHeight
        print("header height set to:", headerHeight)
        cellHeightForDevice = cellHeight

        //weekHeaderLabel.backgroundColor = .blue

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tampering with edgeInset values, try to remove padding as follows

Go to - 
YouStoryboard.storyboard > YourViewController > Attributes inspector > Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets.

[image]

Comment: Whats really happening when I do this? And why is it better than tampering with edgeInset values?